# How to exclude default Java packages in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

[Head First Kotlin](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-kotlin/9781491996683/) states that if your target platform is the JVM, the following are imported by default:

- java,lang.*
- kotlin.jvm.*

If I do not want to have dependencies on Java how do I not import the JVM specific packages?

Comment: How do you going to run Kotlin without JVM? Are you going to use Kotlin/Native?

Answer (score 1):

The default imports depend on the platform context under which the sources are analyzed. The imports you specified, `kotlin.jvm.*` and `java.lang.*`, are specific to Kotlin/JVM sources. You can't affect the default imports.

If you want to avoid accidentally using those imports, then you most likely have plans to compile your code for the other platforms, Kotlin/JS and Kotlin/Native. In this case, the best choice for you would be to have a [multiplatform project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) with the sources placed in a *common* source set: such a source set is analyzed as platform-agnostic code which can't use platform-specific language features and dependencies, and the default imports also don't contain anything that is JVM-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change that, and there is no reason for doing that.
This affects neither performance nor compiled artifact size.
This is just as Kotlin designed.

Comment: How do you insure that you are not picking up any JVM specific stuff in your code  if java.blahblah.thing would be usable a just thing?

Comment: I don’t, because I use JVM Kotlin and it is based on JVM, it cannot run without that JVM stuff. And as I already mentioned it does not bring any problem.

Comment: @CWHolemanII could you please explain the motivation? Do you want to have a cross-platform code?